Where can I find and download a driver debugger for Windows XP?
Our company develops systems that work with hardware using drivers for Windows. At the moment, we needed to make some edits to a driver written in C++ in 2004 for Windows XP. We found several source code files from previous years, but after compiling them, none of them worked with our system, which works with hardware in Windows XP. Now I am looking for tools for debugging drivers in Windows XP, so that I can understand the source code and the driver's operation. I found a link to WinDbg, but I did not find where to download WinDbg for Windows XP. What driver debugging tools are there for Windows XP?

Please, as a new user here, start with the [tour] and read [ask]. Formally, you're not asking a question and the implied question where to find stuff is off-topic.

@UlrichEckhardt: But the implied question "What version of WinDbg works on Win XP?" is on-topic.  Agreed that OP should edit to actually ask that question.

For a lot of reasons (legal, license, security, hardware obsolence) I cannot imagine systems still running on windows XP. Have you ever considered pushing back on this request and telling them it is time to update everything to use more modern hardware/software? This is just a security breach waiting to happen, or at some points you will just no longer be able to buy hardware that can still run XP... I myself would run from a company like this

Microsoft has a paragraph addressing your situation

If you're debugging Windows XP, Windows Server 2003, Windows Vista, or Windows Server 2008 (or using one of these operating systems to run Debugging Tools for Windows), you need to use the Windows 7 release of the debugging tools. It's included in the SDK for Windows 7 and .NET Framework 4.0.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/other-wdk-downloads#standalone-tools-for-debugging-windows-xp-and-windows-vista
The download link on that page is broken but these load: Microsoft Windows SDK for Windows 7 and .NET Framework 4 (Web setup) (ISO disk image)
